# iPhone background color not 100% on change

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, css, web

I'm building a new website and when you hover over something, the background color changes. For instance, I have a Twitter button and you hover over it, the background changes to a blue background color.

But when I'm on my iPhone (it's a responsive site) and I click on an icon, the background will only change to 100% of what your screen size is. If I scroll down the background is not fully changed, I see the white background at the bottom.

Is there some jQuery code or plugin that does the trick?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean the page background, right? Can you provide screenshots or code?

Comment: @LeBen Yeah, I mean the page background. This is the site: boeddo.com/_beta

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is caused by the `height:100%` that you have on the `html` and `body` elements which are then absolutely positioned with `bottom:0`. That forces the `body` element to be the height of the screen, rather than the height of the page, and when you scroll down you're actually scrolling past the end of those elements.

Thus when you change the color on the body it seems only to apply to the top part of the screen. This doesn't seem to be a problem on Firefox, but I'm not really sure whether it's a webkit bug or not - it might just be undefined behaviour.

You can fix it by getting rid of the `height:100%` and `position:absolute` on the `html` and `body` elements, but then you'll also probably want to remove the `top:50%` and `margin-top:-250px` on the container since that will no longer work. Also there's a `top:250px` on the container in the `max-width:620px` media query which will probably have to go.

Now this is obviously not going to give you the same results as your initial CSS, but it does fix the color problems. You'll need to come up with another method for centering your container vertically (assuming that's what you require) that doesn't rely on the body height being 100%. If you need more help with that, let me know in the comments.

Comment: @Quincy Cool - I'm glad you got it working. For future reference, if you decide to stick around on stackoverflow, it'll help if you include a link to codepen or jsfiddle with a simplified version of your problem. You'll get more responses and less downvotes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add it next time :)